# image processing and color detection in java

Tags: java, eclipse, image-processing, color-detection

I am trying to put together a project using Eclipse which will take a saved image and be able to detect certain colors. For example, if the image contained various colored circles (or any shape really) it would be able to specify the color of the circles on screen - red, yellow, pink, etc.

I'm not really sure where to begin with this so any help would be appreciated. I am still learning when it comes to java so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I found some sample code online which was taking an image and separating the colors to red, blue and green using color.getRed(); color.getBlue(); color.getGreen(); - but i'm not quite sure how to extend this to colors such as yellow, pink, brown etc. Although the outcome I am ideally looking for is to detect colors already existing in an image rather than converting the entire image itself to a specific color.

Thanks

Comment: "I'm not really sure where to begin with this so any help would be appreciated" -> too broad.

Comment: If anyone has any sample code relating to color detection from an image, that would be a great starting place. Otherwise any tips on how I should go about creating such code myself.

Comment: If you need code in java, why do you tag your question `C#`. Don't spam tags

Comment: @L.B Java is the language I am using as it is the one I have the most experience with. However I have some experience working with C sharp also so any code in it would still be valuable as I could learn from it and translate into Java as the languages are similar. That is why I used the tag.

Comment: @soki OK, what do you expect from us? sample code or a link to a site is off topic for SO. We answer coding problems here... Not *"write/find a sample code for me"*

Comment: Color composition is something learnt in primary school, did you miss that class?

Answer (score 2):

color.getRed(); color.getBlue(); color.getGreen(); are primary colors, you can get any color combining these values.